# It is possible to give <path> tag a class for css purposes?

Tags: css, html, svg

I'd like to have two paths in my svg with classes so i can toggle opacity when I hover the svg with my mouse.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/class

Comment: Before asking a question here, it is expected that you have at least attempted to write the necessary code yourself and it this is a *very* simple thing for you to try yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answere to this question is easy to find, but anyway: yes it is. See the **Global Attributes** in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path

```css
.shape {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="shape" d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z" fill="orange" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would use the stroke-opacity option.